# Multi Tasking With TAP

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

so I got a TAP like this

```
private async void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<string>(s => textBox1.Text += s);
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WebHelper.GetPosts(progress,cities[cityidx].link,categories[categoryidx].link,GetCurrentDistrict()),
                                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    label1.Text = "completed";
}
```

now if I want to have multiple tasks at once should I put the code in a for loop? or is there a better way?

Comment: You can start multiple tasks and instead of awaiting them immediatly put them in a list. Then do `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());`

Comment: Sidenote: you might want to disable the button while awaiting so to avoid starting new taks when users double click for example.

Comment: You should not use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, my first advice here would be to use [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1), instead of [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netcore-3.1), because it's a newer version and more [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2) one, although the `StartNew` has more options to configure.

Next, you simply call [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1) to release foreground thread before all tasks will complete:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int ind = i; // copy trick to not get always 10 as output
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ind);
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

---

As @PeterBons wisely noticed, once button clicked consider disabling (or ignoring the logic to continue via some state variable like `IsProcessing`) it till the operation will finish in order to escape multiple user clicks.